# Russell: "Three or more lines meet in a point."

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

In this quote (from [this essay](https://users.drew.edu/%7Ejlenz/br-ml-ch4.html)), Russell talks about a theorem showing that "three or more lines meet in a point".

> "In geometry, instead of the tedious apparatus of fallacious proofs
> for obvious truisms which constitutes the beginning of Euclid, the
> learner should be allowed at first to assume the truth of everything
> obvious, and should be instructed in the demonstrations of theorems
> which are at once startling and easily verifiable by actual drawing,
> such as those in which it is shown that three or more lines meet in a
> point. "

What theorem is he talking about, and what is its proof?

Comment: He is not talking about *one* theorem, but about a whole family of them, such as the theorem that states that the three altitudes of a triangle meet in a point.

Comment: B. Russell's viewpoint is mainly about a non-axiomatic  epoch  of maths. This is not the case with contemporary maths.

Comment: @Piquito Only in the beginning is Russell recommending that. I recommend this essay. It is quite good.

Comment: For some inscrutable reason, after reading the title of this post my inner joke completion algorithm immediately continued with "One line says to the other..."

Comment: I have to thank you for sharing this essay but unfortunately, if you are asking about that proof, you have missed the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

José has answered your direct question in the comments. This response is meant to go further.

The point he is making can be found in the opening sentence of the paragraph.

"One of the chief ends served by mathematics, when rightly taught, is to awaken the learner’s belief in reason, his confidence in the truth of what has been demonstrated, and in the value of demonstration."

The point that Russell is trying to make is that when we first learn mathematics we are taught to use an unmotivated set of rules for calculation. When he makes the statement that we should avoid rigor when stating truths that are obvious, he is not saying that these are unimportant. His point is, I believe, to get students to the point where they can see the beauty of mathematics at an earlier stage so they don't abandon their study before they reach a level that they can appreciate the beauty of mathematics.

In fact, the paragraph that contains the text to which you refer follows the question:

"How should the teaching of mathematics be conducted so as to communicate to the learner as much as possible of this high ideal?"

The high ideal he speaks of is found earlier in the essay but boils down to the reason many of us on this site study mathematics. We do it for the beauty of it. We are not studying mathematics for any practical purpose. We do it for the joy of it. We see the art in it.

His point in the statement to which you refer is to get students to appreciate this beauty at a much earlier stage.

Comment: You have certainly read **A Mathematician's Apology** written by the great G.H. Hardy, protector of Ramanujan.

Comment: @Piquito No. I usually don't read stuff like this. I like studying and doing mathematics so essays like the one referred to by nocibambi are refreshing. I looked up "A Mathematician's Apology" and found a pdf. It is 56 pages so I probably won't read it today but I will read it. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: *Beauty is the first test: there is no permanent place in this world for ugly mathematics* This and much many you'll read in "A mathematician's Apology".